# Creating StreamBuilder to keep track whenever there is a change on Sensor value with Realtime Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project to keep track of temperature and humidity sensor whenever they change. I will be working with a ESP32 to send the data to the Firebase, and my App to keep monitoring the values. So if the value goes from 23 to 24 I would like to immediately show the user on my app that change.
I will use a StreamBuilder to keep track of theses changes, But I'm having problems using the Stream.


This is how I the code I'm using to gather the specific user sensor info. This code is at a separate dart file, called auth.dart

```
class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

  //Cria um objeto baseado no Usuario da FirebaseUser
  User _userFromFirebaseUser (FirebaseUser user){
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // Devolve o UID da pessoa
  Future<String> personuid() async{
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    return user.uid;
  }
   // Função para ler o valor da temperatura
  Future<int> getSensorTemperature() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    int result = (await databaseReference.child(user.uid+"/temperature").once()).value;
    print(result);
    return result;
  }

  // Função para ler o valor da humidade
  Future<int> getSensorHumidity() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    int result = (await databaseReference.child(user.uid+"/humidity").once()).value;
    print(result);
    return result;
  }
```

In my home page I attempted to use the StreamBuilder like this:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main page'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton.icon(onPressed: () async {
            await _auth.signOut();
          }, 
          icon: Icon(Icons.logout), 
          label: Text('Logout'))
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _auth.getSensorTemperature(), <-- I get an error here
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError){
            return Container(color: Colors.red,);
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData){
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error I get from the StreamBuilder is:
The argument type 'Futureint' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Streamdynamic'

Comment: What's wrong with what you have so far?  Please edit the question to explain what is not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Just edited it

Comment: You're not actually using streams. You're converting your stream to a future for some reason. Just take your stream, return it, and change your function return type to a `Stream`.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Could you make a answer with that please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually using streams. You were only taking a single event previously. Use the streams that the package make available and then use an `await for` to handle it.

```dart
Stream<int> getSensorTemperature() async* {
  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

  await for(var event in databaseReference.child(user.uid+"/temperature").onValue) {
    yield event.snapshot.value;
  }
}
```

With error handling:

```dart
Stream<int> getSensorTemperature() async* {
  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

  Stream stream = databaseReference.child(user.uid+"/temperature").onValue.handleError((error) {
    print("Error: $error");
  });
  await for(var event in stream) {
    yield event.snapshot.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason it tells me that I need to add Future to it. It doesn't allow Stream<int>, it gives me a red line under it

Comment: await can't be there too.

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF Yeah got it i'll give you a different method.

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF Made an edit. LMK if there is anything else.

Comment: @CristopherMoore I was just finishing my App when I noticed something that went wrong, when I log out of my App It gives me an error exactly at the await part. The error I get is: Exception has occurred.
DatabaseError (DatabaseError(1, com.firebase, Permission Denied)) and my app froze after every attempt to log out, how could I solve this?

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF Which await part?

Comment: This part: await for(var event in databaseReference.child(user.uid+"/temperature").onValue), my firebase rules are secure, I set them to only allow read and write when user is logged in

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF You just need to handle the error from the stream. There may be more elegant methods but I can't tell you more without more code and this should work for now.

Comment: @ChrisopherMoore I got a bigger error this time, I will update the question with the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226021/discussion-between-nilton-schumacher-f-and-christopher-moore).